# Why is importing from a package invalid when the aliased name of package is used?

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

To make it more clear, consider a numpy example :

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
```

This works as expected. But what about this:

```
from np import array
```

The output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-21-d5c81fa93e5f> in <module>()
    ----> 1 from np import array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'np'
```

Once I have set the alias of the imported module numpy as `np`, shouldn't I be able to import something else using np only?

Also, the `id()` of both is the same -- both `numpy` and `np` refer to the same thing.

Comment: `from` is expecting the module name and not the local alias, check `np.array == array`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The module name is still `numpy`, even after you import the module as `np`.

What the `import … as …` syntax basically does is this:

```
np = internal_import_module('numpy')
```

So the `np` is just the local name that get used to refer to the `numpy` module. If you look at the module name of `np`, you can see that it’s still `'numpy'`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__name__
'numpy'
```

Now, the local name of a module is not being used at all when another import statement is being evaluated. So your `from numpy import array` is basically just this:

```
array = internal_import_module('numpy').array
```

Here `array` is again just a local name for the `array` member inside of the `numpy` module. It is however not a member inside of the `np` module because there simply isn’t a module with that name.